# "You could go now" or "You may go now"?

Tags: meaning, difference

"You could go now" or "You may go now"

Which is correct? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context:

"You could go now", might mean "It is perhaps possible for you to go", or "It is possible for you to go now, if some other condition is true.

"You may go now", is more about permission. It might mean "You are allowed to go now" or "I allow you to go now", or even imply "You must go".  In this context "may" doesn't mean "might"  But in very similar sentences it could have a different meaning.

"He may go tomorrow" could be about permission, or it could be about possibility. It might mean "He will possibly go tomorrow."

In spoken English, emphasis on particular words helps reduce the ambiguity.  "You *could* go now"  with the emphasis on could, emphasises the uncertainty in the possibility. It means "It might be possible for you to go, but it probably isn't." Different emphasis can change the meaning.  Moreover the wider context and the prior beliefs of the speakers also affect how any particular sentence will be understood.

Yes. Modal verbs are hard for computers to understand, but humans deal with all this ambiguity pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

**Could** and **May** are both modal verbs for seeking a request, they have the same initial meaning that is to request something.

*Could* and *May* are both correct for expressing either possibility or permission. Due to the usage of your example, I'll just discuss about the differences in expressing permission, but if you need explanation in possibility, you can tell me in the comment.

### Differences between *could* and *may*:

#### 1. Tense

*Could* is mostly used in past tense only, while *May* is used as present as well as past tense.

#### 2. Function

Using *could* is more polite, whereas using *may* is more formal.

#### 3. Pronoun

*Could* is generally used for all three persons in the subject, but *may* generally has **"I"** as its subject.

Comment: Thank you. "Could he call you anytime?" What does it imply please explain to me.

Comment: @AbdullahalMamun Hi, in your example it's about permission here. It means **"Is he allowed to call you anytime?"**. Perhaps "you" are very busy and "he" isn't sure when to call him.

Comment: @AbdullahalMamun Also note that you can use **can** here as well. But using can is more informal and using could is more polite.